# PHP Function - Trapping for Error or Success Result

Tags: php

I'm working on my first function with PHP - it's a login function that calls cURL to login to an API. This is all working well so far, but I would like to add some error checking so that if the login fails or succeeds I can branch for that.

There's 2 possible types of errors that I can see:

1. cURL errors
2. API login errors

If there are no cURL errors the API will return a response in JSON like this for a successful login:

```
{
    "token": "6a2b4af445bb7e02a77891a380f7a47a57d3f99ff408ec57a62a",
    "layout": "Tasks",
    "errorCode": "0",
    "result": "OK"
}
```

and this for a failed login:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Invalid user account and/or password; please try again",
    "errorCode": "212"
}
```

so that should be easy enough to trap for by the error code or result value. If there is a cURL error there could be many types of errors.

Here's the outline of my function at the moment:

```
function Login ($username, $password, $layout) {

    $curl = curl_init();

    // set curl options

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      return json_decode($response, true); 
    }

}
```

and I call it via:

$login = Login($username, $password, $layout);

Looking for advice on how I can return an error if there was a curl error and check the response on the calling page that calls the function.

Comment: You can log the cURL error and return `null` from the function. If you get `null` when calling your function, you know that a cURL error occurred and can continue your code accordingly. Then you can always check your error log to see why it failed. If you get an array back, just check `if ($response['errorCode] > 0) { // Auth error from the API }`

Comment: imo if `Login` returns json on success, then it should either return json on error, or just throw an exception which can be caught and handled outside it, i would also avoid doing the curl request there else your going to start breaking the DRY principle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @larwence-cherone in the comments, you should throw and catch exceptions.

```
// note: made the method name lowercase, because uppercase usually indicates a class
function login ($username, $password, $layout) {

    $curl = curl_init();

    // set curl options   
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        throw new Exception($err);
    } else {
        // returns an associative array
        $result = json_decode($response, true);
        // the status was not OK or if we received an error code.
        // Check the API doc for a recommended way to do this
        if ($result['result'] !== 'OK' || $result['errorCode'] > 0) {
            $errorMessage = $result['errorMessage'];
            // no error message: return a genuine error
            if (!$errorMessage) {
                $errorMessage = 'An undefined error occurred';
            }
            throw new Exception($errorMessage);
        }
        // if no error occurred, return the API result as an
        return $result;
    }    
}
```

call the method in a try/catch block:

```
try {
    $login = login($username, $password, $layout);
    print_r($login);
} catch (Exception $error) {
    echo $error;
}
```

If you want to refine it, you could create your own exception(s) by extending the SPL Exception class.

Comment: Just checking if there's a syntax error in this line `} catch Exception($error) {` - should it be `} catch (Exception $error) {` instead?